# How to keep a UI object in place with auto layout constraints?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a cell that can be in edit mode when a button is pressed, however I can't manage the cell textbox to stay in place. I have taken a screenshot of an example:
[image: Editable cell]

And these are my constraints:
[image: Cell Contraints]

How do I keep the textbox from moving position?

EDIT: Is this what you meant Szu?
[image]

Comment: You should set spacing for your textbox to the right side and remove existing constraint to the left side. You don't need "Lesser" and "Greater" relation. You should use just "Equal" relation.

Comment: I edited my question, is that what you meant because it doesn't work like I meant, I will post more screenshot if you like.